# Converting time to "HH:mm:ss" using Calendar and SimpleDateFormat adds 1 hour

Tags: java, android, time, formatting, timezone

### Request

I need to convert time saved in seconds -> to "HH:mm:ss" (and other formats in the future).

E.g. **`9` seconds -> `"00:00:09"`.**

However, the `Calendar` class always **adds +1 hour**. I assume it is because of my timezone (which is `"Europe/Prague"`) or daylight savings time.

### Testing

First simple usage of `Date` class. Then three times of `Calendar` with different timezones, trying methods `setTimeInMillis()` and `set()`.

```
// Declarations
Calendar cal;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( format );
String result;
```

Date class usage:

```
// Simple Date class usage
Date date = new Date( timeInSecs * 1000 );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( date );             // WRONG result: "01:00:09"
```

Calendar class with "GMT":

```
// Calendar - Timezone GMT
cal = new GregorianCalendar( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ) );

cal.setTimeInMillis( timeInSecs * 1000 );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // WRONG result: "01:00:09"

cal.set( 1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, timeInSecs );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // WRONG result: "01:00:09"
```

Calendar class with "UTC":

```
// Calendar - Timezone UTC
cal = new GregorianCalendar( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );

cal.setTimeInMillis( timeInSecs * 1000 );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // WRONG result: "01:00:09"

cal.set( 1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, timeInSecs );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // WRONG result: "01:00:09"
```

Calendar class with "default" - "Europe/Prague":

```
// Calendar - Timezone "default" (it sets "Europe/Prague")
cal = new GregorianCalendar( TimeZone.getDefault() );

cal.setTimeInMillis( timeInSecs * 1000 );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // WRONG result: "01:00:09"

cal.set( 1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, timeInSecs );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );    // CORRECT result: "00:00:09"
```

**In the last case I got the right result but I do not understand why.**

### Questions

1. **Why the last case works?** (And the one before doesn't?)
2. How should I use the Calendar class to be able to simply pass time in seconds to it (without any parsing)?
3. Is there another solution (another class)? Except for parsing it on my own.

Comment: A duration is not a date. A `Calendar` (and a `SimpleDateFormat)` is not suited to display a duration.

Comment: Ok. So let's assume that I would like to show date and time `9` seconds after today's midnight (and I have the time saved in seconds). I would still have the same problem if I would use `setTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Add a timezone pattern element to your `format` and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TimeZone`(s) don't agree for the `Calendar` and the `SimpleDateFormat` (*except* for the final example). You can use [`SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) to set the same timezone and it should work.

```
// Calendar - Timezone UTC
cal = new GregorianCalendar( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );
cal.setTimeInMillis( timeInSecs * 1000 );
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) ); // <-- like so.
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );
cal.set( 1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, timeInSecs );
result = simpleDateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you are facing this issue. But you can simply write something like.
    `int hours = secs / 3600,`
    `remainder = secs % 3600,`
    `minutes = remainder / 60,`
    `seconds = remainder % 60;`

```
 string displayHours= (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours, 
 displayMinutes= (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes , 
 displaySec = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds ; 

 System.out.println(disHour +":"+ displayMinutes+":"+displaySec );
```

Comment: Thanks. This definetely works but I wanted solution without me doing the parsing. (I will change formats a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
int millis = 9 * 1000;
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String time = df.format(new Date(millis));
Log.i("Duration in seconds: ", time);
```

Comment: This works as well. Thank you. Also thanks that you suggested a solution with use of SimpleDateFormat but without Calendar. Great.